# Вывести по номеру комбинацию факториала(перестановка)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте.
Пользователь вводит `N`!
С этим числом работает метод перестановки. Который в свою очередь выполняется по формуле из комбинаторики(перестановка). Нужно вывести на экран по определенному номеру комбинацию которая соответствует ему.
Проблема в том, что это нужно реализовать без использования массива, коллекций. 
Буду очень благодарен любому ответу.
Кто может, предоставьте пожалуйста пример на языке C#.

Пример

```
-----------------
4!
----------------
1 - 1234
2 - 1243
3 - 1342
4 - 1324
5 - 1423
6 - 1432
----------------
7 - 2341
8 - 2314
9 - 2413
10 - 2431
11 - 2413
12 - 2431
----------------
13 - 3412
14 - 3421
15 - 3124
16 - 3142
17 - 3241
18 - 3214
----------------
19 - 4123
20 - 4132
21 - 4231
22 - 4213
23 - 4312
24 - 4321
----------------

//По перестановке вычислить порядковый номер и по номеру саму перестановку.
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что даже "без использования массива"?

Comment: Какие возникли трудности с написанием кода?

Comment: вы пропустили 2134/2143, добавив пару дубликатов

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83

Comment: Я недавно изучаю программирование, по теории есть некоторые знания, что касается практики почти 0. Виноват в этом сам, ничего не писал, а больше гуглил. 
Как мне сегодня сообщили, нужно вывести чистый алгоритм, который выполнит перестановку. Не знаю, где он будет содержать эти данные, если не в массиве. 
Возможно реализация будет проходить с использованием Set && Subsets. Проверять по номеру. Но для этого нужно реализовать перестановку.
@Brave_Lime

Comment: @kurarora используйте рекурсию

Comment: vp_arth, большое спасибо !!!
Хороший алгоритм !